# where to find some of the maven lifecycle documentation

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

I like to find build, assembly:assembly, generate-sources, where to find the docs of those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read [Maven Book](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/public-book.html), this is excellent and complete reference to Maven. For build life-cycle, refer: http://www.sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/lifecycle.html

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference for life cycles. For individual plugin, you may refer to the plugin documentation (e.g. for assembly plugin, see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)